# Need help closing multiple opened accordion items on the same page but separate sections

Tags: jquery, wordpress, divi

I'm trying to figure out how to close all other opened accordion items on the same page. I'm using Divi as the theme for my Wordpress site. Divi already comes with the ability to have one accordion item open at a time, but if there is another accordion on that same page it won't close the last opened accordion item on that page. I can't seem to find any answers on how to go about this online other then using JQuery is the best way to go about this problem. I'm pretty new to JQuery so I'm not sure if I'm missing something, or if my code isn't working as intended.

Example of HTML:

```
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_accordion et_pb_accordion_2 ally-faq">
    <div class="et_pb_toggle et_pb_module et_pb_accordion_item et_pb_accordion_item_10 et_pb_toggle_close">
        <h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">Your Title Goes Here</h5>
        <div class="et_pb_toggle_content clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="et_pb_toggle et_pb_module et_pb_accordion_item et_pb_accordion_item_11  et_pb_toggle_close">
        <h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">What are your Screen Print Artwork Guidelines?</h5>
        <div class="et_pb_toggle_content clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="et_pb_toggle et_pb_module et_pb_accordion_item et_pb_accordion_item_12  et_pb_toggle_open">             
        <h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">I don't have access to vector artwork, what do I do?</h5>
        <div class="et_pb_toggle_content clearfix"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS classes:

et_pb_toggle_close - Accordion item is currently closed

et_pb_toggle_open - Accordion item is currently open

et_pb_toggle_title - Accordion item's title

To change from close to open is done by clicking on the et_pb_toggle_title class.

Here is my current JQuery code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('.et_pb_toggle_title').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $('et_pb_toggle_title').parent().nextAll().not($this).addClass('et_pb_toggle_close').removeClass('et_pb_toggle_open');
      $('et_pb_toggle_title').parent().prevAll().not($this.parent()).addClass('et_pb_toggle_close').removeClass('et_pb_toggle_open');
    });
});
</script>
```

The logic for the code is to on click of the accordion's title it will:

1. Get the parent of all the accordion items after it. As long as it's not the current accordion item it will add the close accordion class and remove the open one.
2. Get the parent of all the previous accordion items. And like in one it will add/remove classes as long as it isn't the current accordion item.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this script any help with pointing me in the right direction, or pointing out errors with/in the script would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
$('.et_pb_accordion_item').each(function(){
       $(this).addClass('et_pb_toggle_close').removeClass('et_pb_toggle_open')
})
```